# Working (no 401 Client Error) Unofficial Google Api Reader Client

Tags: ruby, google-reader

Is there a working client (in any language, preferably in ruby) that can **currently** retrieve subscriptions (starred, liked, tags are a bonus) from, still the unofficial, [Google Reader API](http://groups.google.com/group/fougrapi)?

I've tried both [this](http://github.com/aurelian/grapi) and [this](http://github.com/nudded/GoogleReaderAPI), but they seem unable to make simple requests, such as http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list, which works perfectly if used on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this is a couple of other posts I found that were similar to this one... so incase its relevant, for ruby, using the google-api-client (for any of the google apis), there's a few ins and outs with authentication when using an api key as opposed to OAuth...

I've outlined this process (using an api key server side) at [the code abode](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/google-api-ruby-client-authorizing-with.html).

You have to explicitly set the authorzation param to nil when constructing the client, otherwise the gem tries to use OAuth to authenticate, so if calling from a server using an api key only, you will always get a 401 Unauthorized. [the code abode - google-api-client for ruby](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/google-api-ruby-client-authorizing-with.html)

```
  require 'openssl'
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  require 'google/api_client'
  client = Google::APIClient.new(:key => 'your-api-key', :authorization => nil)
  search = client.discovered_api('customsearch')

  response = client.execute(
    :api_method => search.cse.list,
    :parameters => {
      'q' => 'the hoff',
      'key' => 'your-api-key',
      'cx' => 'your-custom-search-id'
    }
  )
```